# Extracting rows from data frame with variable string condition in R

Tags: r, extract, subset

Take iris as the data frame, I want to extract all rows and column variables (Petal.Length,Petal.Width,Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width) that have species as a specific value. e.g setosa. it should show 50 entries. I tried aggregate but didnt work. It is the equivalent and of the WHERE clause in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the subset command.

```
data(iris)

dat<-subset(iris,subset=Species=='setosa')
```

Comment: Thanks! slight improvement though subset(iris,subset=iris$Species=='setosa') so when you specify certain columns it works as well.

Comment: @user3241846 - that is not an improvement.  You've already told the function you're using `iris`, so `iris$Species` is not necessary. `subset(iris, Species == "setosa")` is good enough

Comment: Interesting. If you want to reference certain columns you can also use a simple bracket notation: dat<-iris[iris$Species=='setosa',]

Comment: @RichardScriven When I tried using subset(iris[,1:3],subset=Species=='setosa'), it didnt work

Comment: That's because `iris[,1:3]` has removed the `Species` column.  It's the 5th column

Comment: If you only wish to keep columns 1-3 you use the 'select' command.

Or you can use the bracket notation earlier. dat<-iris[iris$Species=='setosa',1:3]

Comment: @Jason yes that works! and so much simpler. I did a quick search and didnt find any select command in R, can you also provide an example.

Comment: Sorry, I meant argument, not command. Here's an example: dat<-subset(iris,subset=Species=='setosa',select=c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",  "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")